# Passing data to a specific View Controller without entering the controller Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I am making a app with many Views. When I am navigating from one View to another I want the data to be sent to a third view without entering the view. I know that it is a way to do this by using this code:

```
let nextView = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("view3") as lastViewController
nextView.data = 1103
```

But if I do it this way and don't move to the view the data won't be saved. How can I save the data without entering it? Do I need to open it?

In the first view:

```
var chosenItem:Int = 0
@IBAction func buttonClicked(sender: AnyObject) {
    if sender.tag == 0 {
        chosenItem = 1
    } else if sender.tag == 1 {
        chosenItem = 2
    } else if sender.tag == 2 {
        chosenItem = 3
    }
}
```

This is how my code looks now:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "toView2" {
        let nextView = segue.destinationViewController as questionAgeViewController
        nextView.firstAnswer = chosenItem
    }
}
```

In the next view I send both the first item and the second. And as you understand this is not the best way to get the information. Is there a better?

Comment: Have you tried using NSUserDefaults?

Comment: Apple docs says: "*You use this method to create view controller objects that you want to manipulate and present programmatically in your application. Before you can use this method to retrieve a view controller, you must explicitly tag it with an appropriate identifier string in Interface Builder. This method creates a new instance of the specified view controller each time you call it.*", so it means you have a instance of **view3**. When you change a property, the data is stored correctly.

Comment: How and when do you check the data?

Comment: When going to another view. I am checking the data at the end when i am going to make a result

Comment: Can you add some code with an example, please?

Comment: The app I am making is a app where you shall answare some questions. Every questions is on its own View. There is some Optional questions so it isn't always the same data. I know that I can send the data from view to view, but that is pretty complicated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you might be looking for a global variable. Use this code to make the variables:

```
struct globalVars {
    static var firstVar = "Your text"
    static var secondVar = Some number
    static var thirdVar = Some array
}
```

In a other view you can access the information like this:

```
let globalText = globalVars.firstVar
println(globalText)
```

To edit the variables just use this code:

```
globalVars.firstVar = "The new text"
```

Comment: This worked, but is there any disadvantage in using global variables instead of singleton?

Answer (score 2):

Create a **singleton class** and add properties into it, as per your requirement.

Now you can set its properties from your firstViewController and access the same from SecondViewController.

```
class Singleton {
  class var sharedInstance: Singleton {
    struct Static {
      static var instance: Singleton?
      static var token: dispatch_once_t = 0
    }

    dispatch_once(&Static.token) {
      Static.instance = Singleton()
    }

    return Static.instance!
  }
}
```

Singleton tutorials for Swift

- http://thatthinginswift.com/singletons/
- http://code.martinrue.com/posts/the-singleton-pattern-in-swift
- http://www.raywenderlich.com/86477/introducing-ios-design-patterns-in-swift-part-1

Comment: I don't know Singelton and I wonder if you know any places where I can learn it?

Comment: Added few tutorial reference links